# Get JSON data from populated listview in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm populating a list view with images and text parsed from JSON. When I click on the list view item, I want to get the image link related to that image.

Is it possible to get the JSON image string (of that image) which I can pass to another activity to display the image in fulscreen?

I tried to use `onitemclick` listener but I'm not able to get the image link from it!

Comment: You can not get Image Url From ImageView but you can get from your Data list with clicked position on listview Item.

Comment: You should set the link as a [tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) on the view. This way you can retrieve it later in the onclick.

Comment: and how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to populate json data in array list and onclicklistner of listview, you will get position which item is clicked. from position you can fetch image URL string from array list and pass image URL string to intent in another activity. using glide library you can download image from image URL and show it in full screen.

Comment: What should i write inside the onclicklistner of listview?

Comment: you can call intent for second activity and passed image link in putExtra.